# How can I check if a combobox is a dropdown or a drop list?

Tags: c++, mfc, combobox

Is there a way to retrieve the type of a CComboBox?

I need to know if it is a "Dropdown" or a "Drop List".

I've tried the following:

```
if (m_MyComboBox.GetStyle() & CBS_DROPDOWN)
   // do some stuff
```

and

```
if (m_MyComboBox.GetStyle() & CBS_DROPDOWNLIST)
   // do some stuff
```

But both expressions seem to evaluate to TRUE regardless of the CComboBox being a dropdown or a drop list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From winuser.h:

```
#define CBS_DROPDOWN          0x0002L
#define CBS_DROPDOWNLIST      0x0003L
```

You need:

```
switch(m_MyComboBox.GetStyle() & CBS_DROPDOWNLIST)
{
  case CBS_SIMPLE:
    // do stuff
    break;

  case CBS_DROPDOWN:
    // do stuff
    break;

  case CBS_DROPDOWNLIST:
    // do stuff
    break;
}
```

Comment: Ok, this was indeed what I needed to get further but... 
Actually ((m_MyCoboBox.GetStyle() & CBS_DROPDOWN) == CBS_DROPDOWN) ALWAYS evaluates to true regardless of the type being dropdown or droplist, while (m_MyComboBox.GetStyle() & CBS_DROPDOWNLIST) == CBS_DROPDOWNLIST) evaluates to FALSE only for a droplist... wow beats my logic ;-)

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying the answer (I've seen that you updated it to also reflect what Shino answered). Because you were first I'm accepting yours as the right answer (I upvoted Shino's because he was the first to give a more complete answer)

Answer (score 6):

Use following code

```
if ((m_MyComboBox.GetStyle() & 3) == CBS_SIMPLE)
{
    //SIMPLE
}
if ((m_MyComboBox.GetStyle() & 3) == CBS_DROPDOWN)
{
    //DROPDOWN
}
if ((m_MyComboBox.GetStyle() & 3) == CBS_DROPDOWNLIST)
{
    //DROPDOWNLIST
}
```